# Does playing your instrument cause it to improve its tonal characteristics?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I have eight guitars but I only play three of them on a regular basis, so some of them just hang on the wall for extended periods of time. After some time I'll feel like changing things so I'll begin playing one that hasn't been played in a while and it doesn't seem to sound as good to me. But if I continue to play it for a few days, then I start to feel good about the way it sounds and I want to play it more and more. I've noticed this on each instrument. Is there any information out there to back this up, or am I a bit loopy here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question!

> Is there any information out there to back this up, or am I a bit
>   loopy here?

You're not `loopy`, no. To expand a little on the already good
   answers from @Tim and @LaurencePayne , based own my own experience
   when playing several basses in a rotation. (I used to have 4 or 5 that I played fairly regularly - no more.) :

- Every instrument - certainly every different model or make - has 
  certain unique characteristics to its sound. When you play one for a 
  while you become accustomed to the sound of that instrument, and your
  ears/brain establish that sound as the norm - the 'right' sound -   even if objectively speaking it might not be particularly good. 
        When you change instruments, its new sound might initially sound    'wrong' to you, simply because it's different than what
  you're    accustomed to. 
  After a while, your ears make the adjustment
  and the    new sound becomes 'the right one'.
        It's not much different than moving into a new place, or a getting    new computer, taking a new job, or other such change from
  what we've    been accustomed to: The new one might actually be much
  better, but    initially you'll feel uncomfortable and uncertain
  because it's new    and different. Sometimes that's called
  "buyer's remorse", which    often wears off after a bit of time, once
  you become adjusted to the    new situation.
- Another factor that might come into play is the difference in the
  playing characteristics of different guitars. String spacing and
  tension, neck dimensions, action - any number of things.
  It may
  be that when you first pick up a guitar after not playing it for a
  while, your technique is not quite up to speed for that guitar - your
  hands/muscle memory are accustomed to the old one. That can be
  detrimental to your sound when playing, and also affect your attitude towards that guitar and its sound - if you you're not feeling quite good about how  you're playing, you might not feel quite good about that guitar and its sound either. After playing the new one for bit, your technique adjusts and
  you're back to form. (This depends a lot on how often you play your
  different guitars, and how much experience in general you have
  playing different ones. If you have two that you play for 10 months
  out of the year, and two others that you play a month each, your
  technique will be better adjusted to those you play frequently.)
- We could speculate that if an instrument has been sitting unplayed
  for a period of time, it could get 'set' in certain ways that would
  affect its sound, but after playing it a for a while, it returns to a
  more suitable state for playing, because your playing 'loosens it up'
  through  friction, motion, etc. For example, it might collect dust which would be shaken off by playing, or the strings might lose some of their elasticity when not played... a number of factors might come into play.
  **This is a notion that needs to be supported with some
  sort of empirical evidence, which I do not have - so I leave it as
  mere speculation.**

---

> As an aside: I tend to very particular about my basses so I never leave an instrument I'm playing hanging on the wall, exposed to the elements and potential damage. Changes in temperature or humidity, dust, sunlight, etc. are not really good for a guitar, particularly over longer periods of time. If I'm not actively playing one of my basses (I only have two that I play now), it goes into the hard shell case and then a closet where I keep them. One I'm playing stays in a gig bag when I'm not playing it. AFAIK that's fairly common practice, unless you have a special room with climate control etc, where you hang them.

Answer (score 4):

It's more likely that *you* gradually fit into the way the instrument works best. I think we all adapt, albeit ever so slightly, to different instruments, and after a few days playing on a specific one, find, unconsciously, the way to get the best out of it. So, yes, in a way, it improves. But not because it's being played - more because *you* are playing it !

Answer (score 2):

Whether dealing with musical instruments, audio gear of anything else, this idea rarely stands up to objective investigation!  But certainly, your relationship with an instrument can and will develop with practice, playing and familiarity.

The answer to your actual question - do its tonal characteristics improve - is probably no.  But 'I start to feel good about the way it sounds' is something we can agree on!

Comment: I guess I don't really need to understand the technical aspect of it so much as whether it's not just something in my imagination, and have others noticed it too

Comment: The answer to your actual question - do its tonal characteristics improve - is probably no.  But 'I start to feel good about the way it sounds' is something we can agree on!

Answer (score 0):

I can speak from the point of view of a stringed instrument player (violin etc).  They most certainly suffer from not being played for extended periods, and go into a kind of hibernation.  Once started being played on again, the vibrations will wake the instrument up and it will certainly feel more alive in a short time.  I don't see why this shouldn't be true for guitars as well, at least for acoustic ones.

Comment: It was just something I've noticed, and wondered if others had noticed the same thing. Thanks for the answer.